# R: how to make predictions using gamboost

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction, boosting

```
library(mboost)
### a simple two-dimensional example: cars data
cars.gb <- gamboost(dist ~ speed, data = cars, dfbase = 4,
                    control = boost_control(mstop = 50))
set.seed(1)
cars_new <- cars + rnorm(nrow(cars))
> predict(cars.gb, newdata = cars_new$speed)
Error in check_newdata(newdata, blg, mf) : 
  ‘newdata’ must contain all predictor variables, which were used to specify the model.
```

I fit a model using the example on the `help(gamboost)` page. I want to use this model to predict on a new dataset, `cars_new`, but encountered the above error. How can I fix this?

Comment: You defined `dist ~ speed` in your `gamboost` function. Shouldn't the prediction be `predict(cars.gb, newdata = cars_new)`?

Comment: In my experience the `newdata` option only requires the predictor (i.e., speed) and not both the predictor and outcome (speed and dist).

Comment: In this case, try `cars_new["speed"]` instead of `cars_new$speed`. The first version keeps the data.frame structure, the latter returns a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`predict` function looks for a variable called `speed` but when you subset it with `$` sign it has no name anymore.

so, this variant of prediction works;

```
predict(cars.gb, newdata = data.frame(speed = cars_new$speed))
```

or keep the original name as is;

```
predict(cars.gb, newdata = cars_new['speed'])
```

Comment: The first version is quite cumbersome. Stick to the second one.